# How to get path to "haxe.exe" from macro/eval?

Tags: haxe

I would like to spawn a child process from haxe eval script (or macro). This child process is also an instance of haxe, compiling the code downloaded/generated by parent. Obviously, i can simply use

```
Sys.command('haxe -cpp $buildDir -main CoreMain $coreDefines');
```

but i would like to use exact path to `haxe.exe` (`haxe` on *nix) if possible. So far i haven't found API to get this path from eval or macro. Am i missing something or there is no such API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about any API options for getting to path to the `haxe` binary, but there was meant to be a [`HAXEPATH environment variable`](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/HaxeManual/issues/43) that you could refer to with `Sys.getEnv()`?

Otherwise you might be able to startup a process, find the path, and write it to a file:

```
function getHaxeBinPath () : String {
    var path = switch ( Sys.systemName () ) {
        case "Windows":
            // Windows Script.
        case "Linux":
            Sys.command ( "echo $( which haxe ) >> exePath.txt" );
            Sys.io.File.getContent ( "exePath.txt" );
        case "BSD":
            // BSD Script.
        case "Mac":
            // Macintosh Script.
        default:
            throw "Unknown Operating System!";
    }

    if ( sys.FileSystem.exists ( "exePath.txt" ) {
        sys.FileSystem.deleteFile ( "exePath.txt" );
    }

    return path;
}
```

but then you'd need a script for each operating system and account for versions of things. If you decide to go with this, I think Windows has a [WHERE](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) command you might be able to use, but it's not really much I know about.

This doesn't seem like it'd work on *nix (because of needing to log in/out for environment variables to update), but you *might* be able to set an environment variable in the process and then get it with `Sys.getEnv()`? Same problem with making a custom thing for each OS though.

Comment: If haxe is already in `PATH`, then i don't see how `which` will do better, than OS resolving path from `haxe ...` command. If haxe is not in `PATH` or i need a different version, then `HAXEPATH` might be a solution. I'll look into that. Thx anyway.

Comment: This is not accurate when you use different haxe versions using haxe_shim / lix.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use macros to access the position information of a type directly located in the Haxe standard library:

```
import haxe.macro.Context;

function resolveHaxePath() : String {
    return switch Context.getType( "StdTypes.Void" ) {
        case TAbstract(_.get() => a,_):
            final pos = Context.getPosInfos( a.pos );
            pos.file.substr( 0, pos.file.lastIndexOf("std") - 1 );
        case _:
            Context.fatalError( "Fail to resolve the compiler's path", (macro _).pos );
    }
}
```